Overlay NavigationStack with content directly under navigation bar
I would like to overlay some content on all views that are in a NavigationStack. The content I would like to be positioned directly under the navigation bar. In the screenshot below, this is exactly how I want the black bar to look and be positioned on all views in the NavigationStack:

How can this be done and work on iPhone and iPad in portrait and landscape? It appears the only way would be to determine the height of the navigation bar and the top safe area inset but I was not able to get anything to work. The goal of this is to show a progress bar at the top of each view in the NavigationStack so a user could see how far they have progressed in a flow with many views.
The screenshot is showing the first view in a NavigationStack that was presented using .fullScreenCover. Here is the code for the first view in the stack:
struct NavigationStackEntryView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = NavigationStackViewModel()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    // I want this Rectangle to be overlayed on all views in the NavigationStack in this position
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 10)
                    
                    NavigationLink("Navigate to 2nd view") {
                        SecondView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                        Button {
                            dismiss()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Cancel")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("First view")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .onAppear {
                print("first view appeared")
            }
        }
    }
}

In this example video I am attempting to show what I want it to look like when a view is pushed onto the stack. The Rectangle() is always there. In the example video I just hardcoded a Rectangle() on each view in the stack. This is not the solution because this Rectangle will really be a progress bar but for demonstration purposes is a Rectangle():


You can achieve this by applying an overlay on every view and setting an offset to the contents of the view, this can be done in multiple ways approaches:
1. Create a Configurator that gets an instance to the NavigationController and modifies it (Best approach):
struct LoaderBar: ViewModifier {
    private let height: CGFloat = 10
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background {
                NavigationConfigurator { nc in
                    guard let progress = UIHostingController(rootView: ProgressView(value: 0.8)).view
                    else { return }
                    nc.navigationBar.addSubview(progress)
                    
                    progress.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                        progress.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nc.navigationBar.bottomAnchor),
                        progress.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height),
                        progress.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nc.navigationBar.centerXAnchor),
                        progress.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nc.navigationBar.widthAnchor)
                    ])
                }
            }
            .offset(y: height)
    }
}

extension View {
    func addLoaderBar() -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(LoaderBar())
    }
}

struct NavigationStackEntryView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink("Navigate to 2nd view") {
                        SecondView()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("First view", displayMode: .inline)
            .addLoaderBar()
        }
    }
}

2. Create a ViewModifier that applies an overlay to every single view in the NavigationStack:
struct LoaderBar: ViewModifier {
    private let height: CGFloat = 10
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .offset(y: height)
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: height)
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func addLoaderBar() -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(LoaderBar())
    }
}

struct NavigationStackEntryView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = NavigationStackViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink("Navigate to 2nd view") {
                            SecondView(viewModel: viewModel)
                                .addLoaderBar()
                    }
                }
                //...
            }
            .addLoaderBar()
            //...
        }
    }
}

3. Create a generic View that applies an overlay to the content of every single view in NavigationStack:
struct OverlayedView<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder let content: Content
    
    private let height: CGFloat = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .offset(y: height)
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: height)
            }
    }
}

struct NavigationStackEntryView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = NavigationStackViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            OverlayedView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink("Navigate to 2nd view") {
                                SecondView(viewModel: viewModel)
                        }
                    }
                    //...
                }
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}


Unfortunately this does not work. When another view is pushed onto the stack, the Rectangle() in OverlayedView is not present. It's only present on the first view in the stack.

I see you did mention to put the OverlayedView on each view in the stack. The problem with that is since it's not overlaying the NavigationStack, when a view is pushed on the bar is not there during that animation. Ideally this bar is overlayed onto the stack so no matter how the views are navigated, the Rectangle() is always there.

I have added a gif to the question to hopefully further clarify what is wanted.

@travis, I have fixed the answer (added maxHeight to the content's frame). I have also added another approach for this (ViewModifier).

@travis I have added another approach for this
